# config stylelint file in Nuxt js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, nuxt.js, stylelint

I'm new using **Nuxt js** therefore same with *nuxt.config.js* file . I'm trying to get how can I set **stylelint** file on my **Nuxt js** project and run it everytime I press save, so the **stylelint** rules will be apply it. I mean same behaviour like with *.eslintrc* but with *.stylelintrc* rules. I already installed *stylelint stylelint-processor-html stylelint-config-standard* packages and set the package.json scripts object with *"lint:css": "stylelint 'src/**/*.vue'"*  so if I run   yarn/npm run lint_css It works. But I want to automate it everytime I press save

nuxt.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
      head: {
        title: 'my-project',
        meta: [
          {charset: 'utf-8'},
          {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
          {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project'}
        ],
        link: [{rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}],
      },
      loading: {color: '#3B8070'},

      plugins: [
      ],

      styleResources: {
        scss: [
          //
        ]
      },
      build: {
        extend(config, {isDev, isClient}) {
          if (isDev && isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
              enforce: 'pre',
              test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
              loader: 'eslint-loader',
              exclude: /(node_modules)/
            })
          }
        }
      },
      modules: ['']
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [stylelint-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-webpack-plugin) webpack plugin:

```
npm install stylelint-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Note: You also need to install stylelint from npm, if you haven't already:

```
npm install stylelint --save-dev
```

Then you have to update the build section on your `nuxt.config.js`

```js
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = async function() {

      // ...

      build: {
        extend(config, {isDev, isClient}) {

          // ...

          // Stylelint
          config.plugins.push(
            new StyleLintPlugin({
              syntax: 'scss' // eg. with options if you need SCSS ;-)
            })
          )
      },
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, it's unlikely you'll need to use `stylelint-processor-html ` in your stylelint configuration object as `.vue` files are now supported out-of-the-box in the stylelint.